# What kind of brush should be used with a Cavalier King Charles Spaniel?

Tags: dogs, grooming

I have a Cavalier King Charles Spaniel puppy. The fur on her coat is thin and long. I would like to brush her to prevent tangles, especially on her ears, but a slicker brush and a pin brush have not seemed to do much of anything. What is the best type of brush to use with her fur type?

Answer (score 7):

A combination brush which is bristle on one side and pin on the other has worked well for me.  The bristle brush is good for her body fur, which is straight and medium-length so it doesn't tend to tangle. I use the pin brush on her ears, which have the long, curly spaniel fur that can get tangled.

The reason I discounted the pin brush initially is that I was looking for one brush to use for all her fur, and the pin brush had no effect on her body fur.  Once I realized the two fur types were so different, I decided to take a combination approach, which has worked well.