# How should I groom my dog?

Tags: dogs, grooming

What is a good brush or comb for my house-kept hound? Should she be brushed/combed in both directions, or just with her coat?

Comment: By good brush, do you mean like is a [wire-brush](http://www.activedogs.com/media/HealthandGrooming/607032_m.png) or [soft-brush](http://www.perfumela.com/images/full5/HairBrushSoft6211.jpg) better than the other?

Comment: What kind of dog is she, and what kind of coat does she have?

Comment: [Brush question 1](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-kind-of-brush-to-use-with-a-cavalier-king-charles-spaniel) and [Brush question 2](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/353/what-is-the-most-effective-brush-for-knots-in-bichon-frise-fur)

Answer (score 4):

The type of dog and coat depends on the type of brush that you should use. This [dog grooming site](http://www.drsfostersmith.com/pic/article.cfm?aid=248) has good information on the types of brushes to use for the type of dogs. From my own experience, when my lab was between the ages of 2 months to 18 months, I was told by his vet to use a rubber brush or a soft brush, like so:
[image]
Now, when he is older than 18 months I have been using a brush similar to an undercoat shedding rake. Honestly, the type of dog and type of fur dictates what type of brush you use.

Answer (score 2):

I have bedlington terriers which have curly non shedding coats. I use a slicker brush in both directions and I have a stainless steel comb to check through the coat. 
Even brushing well can leave mats and running a comb through against the hair growth is a good double check that you have got out all of the tangles. Important for any long haired or curly dogs. 
Mats probably won't be an issue with a short haired dog but I would still use a slicker brush.

Answer (score -1):

Brush with the coat, brushing against it can be uncomfortable for the dog. Find a good brush. Something like this https://www.rayallen.com/evolution-self-cleaning-slicker-brush/